# Javascript Hangman game how to save a word that a user has entered

Tags: javascript

Hello and happy thanksgiving everyone. So I am trying to write a hangman game that allows a user to put in a six character word and another person then has to guess that letters in the word. Like any hangman game. Problem is i'm unsure of how to write my saveWord function. Here is the HTML:

```
<html>
<title>HangMan</title>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="hangman.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hangmanstyle.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="gameover"></div>
<table align="center">
<tr>
<td align="left"><img alt="Bar" src="img/bar.jpg"/></td>
<td width="50px"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
 <table>
 <tr>
   <td width="150px"></td>
   <td><img alt="Pole" src="img/pole.jpg"/></td>
   <td valign="top" width="400px">
     <table align="right">
     <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td><img id="head" alt="Head" src="img/head.jpg"/></td>
       <td></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td style="vertical-align:top;" align="right"><img id="arm1" alt="Arm1" src="img/arm1.jpg"/></td>
       <td align="center"><img id="body" alt="Body" src="img/body.jpg"/></td>
       <td style="vertical-align:top;" align="left"><img id="arm2" alt="Arm2" src="img/arm2.jpg"/></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td><img id="leg1" alt="Leg1" src="img/leg1.jpg"/></td>
       <td></td>
       <td><img id="leg2" alt="Leg2" src="img/leg2.jpg"/></td>
     </tr>
     </table>
     </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
   <td width="50px"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td align="center" colspan="2"><img alt="Base" src="img/base.jpg"/></td>
  </tr>
  </table>

  <div id="enterWordContainer" align="center">
Enter a six letter word for hangman:  <input id="hangManWord" type="text" value="" />
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="saveWord();"/>
 </div>
<div id="error" align="center"></div>

<div id="wordAnswer" align="center">
<div id="letter0" class="letterAnswer"></div>
<div id="letter1" class="letterAnswer"></div>
<div id="letter2" class="letterAnswer"></div>
<div id="letter3" class="letterAnswer"></div>
<div id="letter4" class="letterAnswer"></div>
<div id="letter5" class="letterAnswer"></div>
</div>
<br class="clearBoth" />  

<div id="letterContainer">
<table align="center">
<tr>
  <td>
    Guess a letter: <input class="letterInpt" id="letter" type="text" value="" />
    <input type="button" onclick="checkLetter('letter');" value="Guess"/>
   </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </div>

<div id="newGame" align="center">
 <input id="newGameBtn" type="button" value="New Game?" onclick="newGame();" />
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Heres the CSS:

```
  body
 {
 }

.letterInpt
{
width:  45px;
height: 35px;
font-weight: bolder;
font-size: 1.5em;
text-align: center;
}

#letterContainer
{
display:none;
}

#head 
{
  visibility:hidden;
  }

  #body
  { 
  visibility:hidden;
  }

  #arm1
  {
   visibility:hidden;
  }

   #arm2
 {
   visibility:hidden;
 }

  #leg1
  {
  visibility:hidden;
  }

  #leg2
  {
  visibility:hidden;
  }

 #error
 {
display: none;
color: #E00;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
}

 #wordAnswer
{
 display: none;

  float: left;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
}

 .letterAnswer
{
 width: 35px;
height: 35px;
border: 1px solid #CCC;
margin-left: 7px;
float:left;
position: relative;
left: -50%;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 2em;
}

.clearBoth 
{ 
 clear:both; 
}

#gameover
{
background-color: #EEE;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 5em;
width:700px;
height:100px;
position:fixed;
top:50%;
left:50%;
margin-top:-150px;
margin-left:-350px;
display: none;
}

#newGameBtn
{
display: none;
}
```

And heres the js that i have gotten so far. Its really not much at all.

```
var word = "";

function saveWord(word){
if(document.getElementById('hangManWord').innerHTML = word)
{
}

function wordAnswer(){
}
function checkLetter('letter'){
}
function newGame(){
}
```

of course my js does not work but i feel like i am on the right track i just need the extra push to help me start. Thank you for helping! Also how would i check to see if the letters a right or wrong. I have an idea I feel like i'm probably going to have to use an array for that but i am not sure. Any help is appreciated! thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of saving the word, you could simply have an `<input>` box and get the value submitted using

```
var s = $('#inputbox').val();
```

In terms of checking if the character guessed is in the word, you can do this:

```
//s is the word that the user previously submitted
function checkLetter(letterGuessed) {
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        if(letterGuessed == s.charAt(i)) {
            //you guessed right!
        }
        else {
            //you guessed wrong :(
        }
    }
}
```

The previous code will break down the word submitted into its individual characters. From there, it will assess each character and see if it's equal to the letter that the user guessed (stored as `letterGuessed`). Simply call the function every time a user guesses a letter. Of course, you will have to modify the comments I made in the `if`/`else` statements to suit your needs.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do:

```
var txtWord = document.getElementById("hangManWord");
txtWord.style.display = 'none';
```

It will hide the input and you can still access the value inside with:

```
txtWord.value;
```